# Div with explicitly defined dimensions is scaling size with viewport width?

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, media-queries

I have two divs in a container: one containing an image and the other containing text. The image container has the set dimensions `width: 250px;` and `height: 240px;`, but when the screen (and the containing div) is made narrow enough, the image container begins to decrease in size in addition to the other div, who is set to `width: auto;`.

I suspect that this is caused by the text in the second inner div requiring a certain amount of space and consequently 'pushing' the image container inward, but using `word-break: break-word;` didn't solve the issue.

Style:

```css
/* "imagecontainer" and "credentials" are contained within "info-container" */

.subsection .info-container {
    display: flex;
}

.subsection .imagecontainer {
    width: 250px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.subsection .imagecontainer img {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.subsection .credentials {
    width: 600px;
    height: 230px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
}

/* This problem occurs at pageWidth<920px, when this media query would be in effect: */

@media only screen and (max-width: 920px) {
    .subsection .credentials {
        width: auto;
        border-right: none;
    }
}
```

Markup:

```html
<div class="subsection">
  <div class="info-container">
    <div class="imagecontainer">
      <img src="data/users/images/5d7d03b1d0013.png">
    </div>
    <div class="credentials" style="width: auto;">
      <div class="name">Test User</div>
      <div class="location">Albany, New York</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="actions-container">
      <div class="action">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="viewprofile?id=5d7d03b1d0013">View profile</a>
      </div>
      <div class="action">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="connect?id=5d7d03b1d0013">Make Connection</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Expected**: only the div containing text will adjust its width in response to a change in viewport width.

**Actual**: both the image-containing div and the text-containing div decrease in size.

**EDIT:** Markup added

Comment: Could you provide markup also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent container of that image container has `display: flex;`. If you don't define anything for the child elements, they will be allowed to shrink.

To avoid this, you can add `flex-shrink: 0` (meaning it *must* not become any smaller) to `.subsection .imagecontainer`.